# What is the deconstructor in "Lego Batman 2" inspired by?

Tags: dc, batman, lego, lex-luthor

In the video game *Lego Batman 2* there is a device called the deconstructor, a ray-gun powered by kryptonite that causes jet-black objects like Batman's equipment and vehicles to tear itself apart. Did this concept exist before the game, and where does it come from? Does such a device appear anywhere outside of the game? (Side note: there is also a movie based on the game)

[image: A Lego Lex Luthor in what seems to be a power suit, gripping the deconstructor in his right hand]

Comment: Looks to me like [Dark is Evil](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/DarkIsEvil) plus [Tron Lines](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TronLines) plus [Sickly Green Glow](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SicklyGreenGlow).  It's like Lego with tropes!

Comment: The design barely looks like the power disruptor he made from the Justice League show (a stick going through a hole at the edge): https://youtu.be/YrKd_zI-PhY?t=93

Answer (score 5):

The **Power Disruptor** that Lex uses in the *Justice League* TV show does strongly resemble the Deconstructor.

[image]